# Gray images are being rendered distorted in cordova-based app

Tags: ios, cordova, svg, ios11

After updating an iPad to iOS 11 a customer noticed that some SVG files are being rendered distorted sometimes. It appears that this only happens, if another rendering operation is being performed and this element overlays the SVG files.

[image]

Has anyone else had this problem yet and has a solution? It would be great to keep the SVG files. Prior iOS 11 and on Android I've never had that problem.

After some tests I'm certain this happens only to gray images. Regardless of being an SVG or PNG.

It seems that sometimes it even renders the wrong image.

How it should look like:

[image: How it should look like]

After creating a dialog:

[image: After creating a dialog]

After destroying the dialog:

[image: After destroying the dialog]

Comment: Is this in Safari?

Comment: Ahh sorry, forget to mention that this is a Cordova-based app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my problem. It has been caused by this CSS class:

```
.desaturate {
    opacity: 0.5;
    filter: gray;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```